# mysql jdbc: what is column size for BIGINT?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

mysql jdbc: what is column size for BIGINT?

jdbc:

id BIGINT(20)

```
ResultSet columns = databaseMetaData.getColumns("foo", "bar", "table", "id");
columns.next();
int columnSize = columns.getInt(7);
```

the columnSize is 19. Is it 19 bytes?

Comment: do you need to pull the data of 7th coloumn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: What is column size for BIGINT?

The MySQL `BIGINT` datatype is a 64-byte signed integer. From a JDBC resultset, that can be handled in Java as a `long`.

With the unsigned variant, the MySQL `BIGINT UNSIGNED` dataype, that could be handled as `java.math.BigInteger`.  (The maximum value of MySQL `BIGINT UNSIGNED` exceeds the maximum value of Java `long`.)

Q: Is it 19 bytes?

The longest string value that MySQL will return for a `BIGINT` would be **20** characters. The lowest possible value for a MySQL BIGINT, represented as a character string is `'-9223372036854775808'`. (That's 19 digits, but an extra character is required for the minus sign.)

The largest value of `BIGINT` would have a string representation of **19** characters.

For the unsigned variant `BIGINT UNSIGNED` the largest value would be represented as 20 decimal digits, thus **20** characters.

In terms of storage in the MySQL database, the BIGINT datatype requires **eight** bytes.